# Can I use positive lookbehind to return a match in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose that I want to find all words in a given string that start with b and end with ing . However, I only want to return the portion of the
word that precedes the ing. Thus, if the word is bailing, I should only
match and return bail.

The below Ruby regex will certainly match:

```
\bt[a-zA-Z]*ing\b
```

but it doesn't return just the "bail" portion.  Can I use some kind of lookahead or lookbehind assertion?  If not, what is a good way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

```
words = "booster bailings balling failing"
words.scan /(?<=\b)b\w*?(?=ing\b)/
#⇒ ["ball"]
```

Comment: Why the positive lookbehind rather than simply `\b`, which has zero-width?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It just looks clearer to me: it reads “after this and before that.” Like a matter of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to extract the desired information.

```
str = "blathering fumbling blinging bérgering blings"

str.scan(/\bb[[:alpha:]]*(?=ing\b)/)
  #=> ["blather", "bling", "bérger"]

str.scan(/\b(b[[:alpha:]]*)ing\b/).flatten
  #=> ["blather", "bling", "bérger"]
```

whereas

```
str.scan(/\bb[a-zA-Z]*(?=ing\b)/)
  #=> ["blather", "bling"]
```